# How to write/represent dynamic text in ArcMap for subtitle

Tags: arcmap, layouts, dynamic-text

I am not really pro in ArcMap designing but I am preparing some layouts (different paper sizes and formats)in ArcMap 10.8 to be published in WebGIS for the printer widget application under WebGIS.

In one part I have to add the title and subtitle to the layout and I have used the following codes for them :

```
<dyn type="document" property="title"/>
<dyn type="document" property="subtitle"/>
```

The title would be shown correctly but the subtitle does not appear.
I thought maybe it has to do with the text . So did changes the size, the format and made the text as rectangle text but still is the same.
I am wondering if there is another way to show the subtitle?

Comment: Please do not delete and repost questions. Doing so might convince the SE spam defenses to ban your account.

Comment: Creating new accounts and reposting from them is also problematic.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts in order to [circumvent a question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)  Please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.